# How to import file conditionally @ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular in SSR

Tags: angular, ckeditor, angular-universal

I'm stuck in Angular Universal/SSR  @ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular. When I import **ClassicEditor**

`import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';`

then receive error **window** is **undefined**. I'm tried many options but can't solve these issues. Now I want to import  **ClassicEditor** only for the browser platform. But issues are

```
this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId);
```

isBowser value receive true|false after initialize components constructor.
Anyone help me how to import a file conditionally like below:

```
if(isBowser){
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
if(isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)){
  import('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic').then(i => {
    this.ClassicEditor = i.default;
  };
}
```